# How to build CaseStatement for Ageing

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case

I am a newbie here and any help would be much appreciated.  I need to create a report with ageing set to >3 months, >6 months, >9 months.

The report should have only 3 columns (3 months, >6 months, >9 months).  In the table/database assume we only have two fields.  One is WELL_ID which identifies the name of the well and RECORD_DATE (mm/dd/yyyy) which identifies the last time this WELL was tested. We want the report to breakdown which well has not been tested in 3 months or >6 months or >9 months.

I believe a case statement can be put together to create this result set but I am drawing a blank on how to do so.  If anyone can post solution with Case Statement then that would be much appreciated.  If they can even take the time to explain the solution to me then that would be even better to help me understand.

Regards,

SQL Newbie

Comment: Sure seems like a `case` statement would be involved.  Sample code, sample data, and desired results might even clarify the issue to help someone figure out what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 3 columns >3 months, >6 months, >9 months returned each one with well_id, I can show you how to do this in SQL. However, you better off doing this on the report level, and only retrieving each column from SQL separately. This is trivial and others already gave you some examples of this.

Let's start. First of all, the datediff in SQL behaves not how people expect it to behave. You can read everything about it in [this article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/datediff-function-demystified). Let's borrow a function from there:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fnMonthsApart]') AND type in (N'FN'))
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fnMonthsApart
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnMonthsApart
(
        @FromDate DATETIME,
        @ToDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
        RETURN  CASE
                       WHEN @FromDate > @ToDate THEN NULL
                       WHEN DATEPART(day, @FromDate) > DATEPART(day, @ToDate) THEN DATEDIFF(month, @FromDate, @ToDate) - 1
                       ELSE DATEDIFF(month, @FromDate, @ToDate)
               END
END
GO
```

Excellent! Now let's define our table:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Well]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Well]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Well](
  [WELL_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [RECORD_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Well] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [WELL_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And some sample data:

```
declare @date datetime = dateadd(d,-1,getdate())


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-12,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-9,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-9,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-9,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-9,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-9,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-6,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-6,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-6,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-6,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-3,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-3,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (dateadd(m,-3,@date))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Well]([RECORD_DATE]) VALUES (@date)
GO
```

So far, so good.

Now, the trick is retrieve the three columns separately and then join them together in a single recordset. Here is how this can be done:

```
declare @date datetime = getdate();
with AgeGrouping as
(select 
  WELL_ID,
  dbo.fnMonthsApart(record_date,@date) MonthsAgo,
  case 
    when dbo.fnMonthsApart(record_date,@date) >= 9 then 1 
    when dbo.fnMonthsApart(record_date,@date) >= 6 then 2 
    when dbo.fnMonthsApart(record_date,@date) >= 3 then 3 
    else 4
  end AgeGroup,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by  
    case 
      when dbo.fnMonthsApart(record_date,@date) >= 9 then 1 
      when dbo.fnMonthsApart(record_date,@date) >= 6 then 2 
      when dbo.fnMonthsApart(record_date,@date) >= 3 then 3 
      else 4
    end 
  order by WELL_ID) RowNumber
from well
),
MoreThan9Group as
(select * from AgeGrouping where AgeGroup = 1
),
MoreThan6Group as
(select * from AgeGrouping where AgeGroup = 2
),
MoreThan3Group as
(select * from AgeGrouping where AgeGroup = 3
)
select g1.WELL_ID MoreThan9,g2.WELL_ID MoreThan6,g3.WELL_ID MoreThan3
from MoreThan9Group g1 full join MoreThan6Group g2 on (g1.RowNumber = g2.RowNumber)
full join MoreThan3Group g3 on ((g1.RowNumber = g3.RowNumber) or (g2.RowNumber = g3.RowNumber))
```

Note, that I have `>=` instead of `>` in this SQL. This is because the difference between 1st of January and 2nd of April is more than 3 month, but the 3 is the number that is returned when we compare them. So, the result of 3 qualifies under your requirements and hence we change `>` to `>=` to include it.

And this is it.

Here is [SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/243ef/2).

Answer (score 0):

well I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. I've not try it out yet.

The CASE statement checks the value returned by the DATEDIFF function. Depending on this value being > 9 or > 6 or > 3 or <= 3, the test_Status is determined.

```
SELECT well_ID,
       record_Date,
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(month, record_Date, GETDATE()) >= 9
    THEN 'Not Tested In More Than 9 Months'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(month, record_Date, GETDATE()) >= 6
    THEN 'Not Tested In More Than 6 Months'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(month, record_Date, GETDATE()) >= 3
    THEN 'Not Tested In More Than 3 Months'
    ELSE 'Tested Within Last 3 Months'
END AS test_Status
FROM WellTable;
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There is no MONTH_BETWEEN in Sql Server.

Comment: @zespri sorry I forgot to ask which DBMS is he using. so for SQLServer I believe `DATEDIFF` will do the job?

Comment: Datediff works, though it needs a few more parameters.  QUestion was tagged SQL-server.

Comment: Totally missed that out. Hope you guys can help him out here.

Comment: syntax is DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )...so datediff(mm,record_Date, sysdate) (or something close to that) should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can first calculate the number of months between the RECORD_DATE and today's date according to the following logic:

a) if the day part of the RECORD_DATE > day part of today's date+1, then # of months = # of months obtained using DATEDIFF - 1

b) if the day part of the RECORD_DATE is not > day part of today's date+1, then # of months = # of months obtained using DATEDIFF

Then, based on the # of months, the Status is determined.

```
WITH month_interval AS
(
    SELECT
        WELL_ID,
        CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(DAY, RECORD_DATE) > DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE())+1 THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, RECORD_DATE, GETDATE())-1
            ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, RECORD_DATE, GETDATE())
        END num_months
    FROM WellTable
)
SELECT 
    wt.WELL_ID,
    wt.RECORD_DATE,
    CASE 
        WHEN mi.num_months >= 9 THEN 'Not Tested In More Than 9 Months'
        WHEN mi.num_months >= 6 THEN 'Not Tested In More Than 6 Months'
        WHEN mi.num_months >= 3 THEN 'Not Tested In More Than 3 Months'
        ELSE 'Tested Within Last 3 Months'
    END AS TEST_STATUS
FROM WellTable wt
INNER JOIN month_interval mi
ON wt.WELL_ID = mi.WELL_ID;
```